# Bootstrap: a buttons allowed inside navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#callout-buttons-context-usage) says:

> While button classes can be used on `<a>` and `<button>` elements, only
>   `<button>` elements are supported within our nav and navbar components.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding something, but I can use `<a>` links within nav components (already doing it). So, what does that paragraph mean?

Comment: I followed your link, however, I could not find the quoted text anywhere on that page.

Comment: Link should be this one: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#callout-buttons-context-usage

Comment: Thanks for the edition!

Answer (score 0):

Referring to: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#callout-buttons-context-usage

The information does appear to be unclear or ambiguous; however, Stack Overflow is probably not the best place to address this issue. You can open an issue on their GitHub repository: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll do it